# How to tell what the user answered for the location service prompt?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, geolocation

I am using the ALAssetLibrary to grab the original creation date of a photo. When I do so, the location service prompt pops up asking the user if the app can access geodata. I understand the need for this (even though I'm not using geodata). However, how do I know what the user responded? I need to be able to save the response so my code can take the appropriate path next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are talking of location services, you can use the method in `CLLocationManager`.

```
if ( [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] != kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // Your app is not authorized.
}
```